# Xcode 5 and shared Schemes

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5

I'm having an annoying issue with Xcode 5 and the shared schemes.

In my team (we're just two, but hey! it's still a team) we're sharing some Schemes to run the app with different configurations (Debug, QA, Release, ...)

Well now Xcode 5 seems to change the `BlueprintIdentifier` setting of each scheme based, from what I can understand, on the machine of the developer. And of course the change get's noticed bit git and we either have to checkout them, or commit. Both solution don't make sense...

**Any idea on how to fix it?** I did a google search but found nothing for Xcode 5...

I don't want to give up on those shared configurations! A solution I can came up with to keep having the shared Schemes tracked is unshared them, copy them in a dedicated test folder, then using a strategy like the one used for the Pods to copy those schemes locally, where Xcode can mess up with them without us noticing. Something like a `schemes` script that reads a `Schemefile` file which lists the schemes to copy from the `Schemes/` folder, and a `Schemefile.lock` that is updated every time there's some change and that is read by the Xcode build process in order to make sure everything is up-to-date.

This seems a lot of work for such a tiny thing, so before jumping head down into it I would like to know if anyone has some better solution to propose.

Cheers :)

Comment: It's been a while since you asked this. If you found the solution would you mind posting an answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm assuming you're using CocoaPods because you mentioned it in your question.

I've had this issue for a while and just recently discovered that some of my shared schemes are not getting their `BlueprintIdentifier` changed with the others. Upon investigation, I noticed that the untouched schemes had a `Pods` target under `builds` that was missing–as in it was listed in red like this: `Pods (missing)`. My theory is that `pod install` and various Xcode events (i.e. crashing, launching, etc) were causing the scheme to change its `BlueprintIdentifier`s because they had a reference to a `Pod` target in the scheme build settings.

I removed the `Pods` reference in all of my schemes and have not been able to reproduce the `BlueprintIdentifier`change since. My target that depends on `Pods` has `libPods.a` specified under `Link Binary With Libraries` in `Build Phases` and set to required, so it still gets compiled before the main target.

Note that switching between branches with this change and without this change might still produce modifications to the scheme files.

Comment: Hey Wes, thanks for answering! It's been a while since I posted this question, so long that I'm not part of that team anymore!

I didn't find any solution myself, but what you wrote regarding the Pods actually sound like something that could have happened on that project. So I'm gonna mark this as the selected answer :)

Hopefully this was just some weird edge case... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Wes's answer didn't specifically fix this issue for me, but it did lead me to the right place. The solution for me was to turn "Find Implicit Dependencies" from "off" (unchecked) to "on" (checked) from the Edit Scheme screen for the Scheme that keeps changing.